# How to load .plist files in java Webobjects code

Tags: plist, webobjects

I want to load the .plist files and store in com.webobjects.foundation.NSDictionary variable.

The piece of code which was earlier

```
 private NSDictionary variable;

 try{
   variable = OWWOFileUtilities.loadConfigFile("xxxxx.plist", null);
 }

  variable.objectforkey("string");
```

Now the OWWOFileUtilities is not used anymore, So I want the alternate way to load the .plist into my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See,

```
com.webobjects.foundation.NSPropertyListSerialization.dictionaryForString(String value)
```

Apache configuration classes also support loading `plist`s.

Comment: Thanks @user1452701 ... Able to pull up the property values as required